# Editing text in Bash

Tags: bash, file, awk, text, sed

I am trying to edit text in Bash, i got to point where i am no longer able to continue and i need help.

The text i need to edit:

```
Symbol  Name    Sector  Market Cap, $K  Last    Links
 AAPL
Apple Inc
Computers and Technology
2,006,722,560
118.03
 AMGN
Amgen Inc
Medical
132,594,808
227.76
 AXP
American Express Company
Finance
91,986,280
114.24
 BA
Boeing Company
Aerospace
114,768,960
203.30
```

The text i need:

```
Symbol,Name,Sector,Market Cap $K,Last,Links
AAPL,Apple Inc,Computers and Technology,2,006,722,560,118.03
AMGN,Amgen Inc,Medical,132,594,808,227.76
AXP,American Express Company,Finance,91,986,280,114.24
BA,Boeing Company,Aerospace,114,768,960,203.30
```

I already tried :

```
sed 's/$/,/' BIPSukol.txt > BIPSukol1.txt | awk 'NR==1{print}' BIPSukol1.txt | awk '(NR-1)%5{printf "%s ", $0;next;}1' BIPSukol1.txt | sed 's/.$//'
```

But it doesnt quite do the job.
(BIPSukol1.txt is the name of the file i am editing)

Comment: Is the first line always the same?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I and others answered this same question about a week ago at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/621160/133219.

Comment: @Cyrus -- You cheated -- but I like it `:)`. Drop a comment when/if you undelete. Doing it in two-lines, that deserves an UV.

Comment: @Ed Morton I am sorry, i didnt realize that there is a person asking the same question. Its actually college task and i guess i am not the only one asking here, I will delete the post, just give me a few minutes :)

Comment: Grollda, that's why it's encouraged to use search functionality now coming to your task of you use those answers teacher could catch you guys :) :) (on a lighter note) you could use this thread to have these different answers. I am not sure what rule says on SO on this one may be @Ed Morton sir and other respected members could guide(if I am not bothering here) on this one(if there is a way to make dupe from another site which I am not aware of honestly) cheers.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Yes, I cheated but only a little bit. :) I've undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is you do not have consistent delimiters between your fields. Some have commas, some don't and some are just a combination of 3-fields that happen to run together.

The tool you want is `awk`. It will allow you to treat the first line differently and then condition the output that follows with convenient counters you keep within the script. In `awk` you write **rules** (what comes between the outer `{...}` and then `awk` applies your rules in the order they are written. This allows you to "fix-up" your hap-hazard format and arrive at the desired output.

The first rule applied `FNR==1` is applied to the 1st line. It loops over the fields and finds the problematic `"Market Cap $K"` field and considers it as one, skipping beyond it to output the remaining headings. It stores a counter `count = NF - 3` as you only have 5 lines of data for each Symbol, and skips to the next record.

When `count==n` the next rule is triggered which just outputs the records stored in the `a[]` array, zeros `count` and deletes the `a[]` array for refilling.

The next rule is applied to every record (line) of input from the 2nd-on. It simply removes any whitespece from the fields by forcing `awk` to recalculate the fields with `$1 = $1` and then stores the record in the array incrementing `count`.

The last rule, `END` is a special rule that runs after all records are processed (it lets you sum final tallies or output final lines of data) Here it is used to output the records that remain in `a[]` when the end of the file is reached.

Putting it altogether in another cut at `awk`:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            if ($i == "Market") {
                printf ",Market Cap $K"
                i = i + 2
            }
            else
                printf (i>1?",%s":"%s"), $i
        print ""
        n = NF-3
        count = 0
        next
    }
    count==n {
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            printf (i>1?",%s":"%s"), a[i]
        print ""
        delete a
        count = 0
    }
    {
        $1 = $1
        a[++count] = $0
    }
    END {
        for (i=1;i<=count;i++)
            printf (i>1?",%s":"%s"), a[i]
        print ""
    }
' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

Note: you can simply select-copy the script above and then middle-mouse-paste it into an xterm with the directory set so it contains `file` (you will need to rename `file` to whatever your input filename is)

```
$ awk '
>     FNR==1 {
>         for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
>             if ($i == "Market") {
>                 printf ",Market Cap $K"
>                 i = i + 2
>             }
>             else
>                 printf (i>1?",%s":"%s"), $i
>         print ""
>         n = NF-3
>         count = 0
>         next
>     }
>     count==n {
>         for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
>             printf (i>1?",%s":"%s"), a[i]
>         print ""
>         delete a
>         count = 0
>     }
>     {
>         $1 = $1
>         a[++count] = $0
>     }
>     END {
>         for (i=1;i<=count;i++)
>             printf (i>1?",%s":"%s"), a[i]
>         print ""
>     }
> ' file
Symbol,Name,Sector,Market Cap $K,Last,Links
AAPL,Apple Inc,Computers and Technology,2,006,722,560,118.03
AMGN,Amgen Inc,Medical,132,594,808,227.76
AXP,American Express Company,Finance,91,986,280,114.24
BA,Boeing Company,Aerospace,114,768,960,203.30
```

(**note:** it is unclear why you want the `"Links"` heading included since there is no information for that field -- but that is how your desired output is specified)

**More Efficient No Array**

You always have afterthoughts that creep in after you post an answer, no different than remembering a better way to answer a question as you are walking out of an exam, or thinking about the one additional question you wished you would have asked after you excuse a witness or rest your case at trial. (there was some song that captured it -- a little bit ironic `:)`

The following does essentially the same thing, but without using arrays. Instead it simply outputs the information after formatting it rather than buffer it in an array for output all at once. It was one of those type afterthoughts:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            if ($i == "Market") {
                printf ",Market Cap $K"
                i = i + 2
            }
            else
                printf (i>1?",%s":"%s"), $i
        print ""
        n = NF-3
        count = 0
        next
    }
    count==n {
        print ""
        count = 0
    }
    {
        $1 = $1
        printf (++count>1?",%s":"%s"), $0
    }
    END { print "" }
' file
```

(same output)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following(written and tested in GNU `awk`). Considering that(by seeing OP's attempts) after header of Input_file you want to make every 5 lines into a single line.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  NF--
  match($0,/Market.*\$K/)
  matchedPart=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  firstPart=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
  lastPart=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  gsub(/,/,"",matchedPart)
  gsub(/ +/,",",firstPart)
  gsub(/ +/,",",lastPart)
  print firstPart matchedPart lastPart
  next
}
{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
}
++count==5{
  print val,$0
  count=0
  val=""
  next
}
{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$0
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

OR if your `awk` doesn't support `NF--` then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  match($0,/Market.*\$K/)
  matchedPart=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  firstPart=substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
  lastPart=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  gsub(/,/,"",matchedPart)
  gsub(/ +/,",",firstPart)
  gsub(/ +Links( +)?$/,"",lastPart)
  gsub(/ +/,",",lastPart)
  print firstPart matchedPart lastPart
  next
}
{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
}
++count==5{
  print val,$0
  count=0
  val=""
  next
}
{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")$0
}
' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Looks like your header/first line needed special manipulation because we can't simply set `,` for all spaces, so taken care of it in this solution as per shown samples.

Comment: Your code almost works, the only thing that is wrong in your solution is that there are too many commas in the first line 

Your solution: 

     `Symbol,Name,Sector,Market,Cap,,$K,Last,Link`

What i need:

     '`Symbol,Name,Sector,Market Cap $K,Last,Links`

Comment: @Grolldash, already taken care of it, please check my edited solution once :) and let me know then.

Comment: I am sorry for bothering, there is still just one more comma after `Cap`
And i just noticed that in the first line i also need to delete the word `Links` and the coma before it

Comment: @Grolldash, no issues, done fixed it now, kindly do let me know how it goes(to remove links I have used `NF--` here and tested it with GNU `awk`)?

Comment: There are still some things that are not the way it should be. I will try to find the issues myself so i don't bother you so much. If i find the solution, i will post it here :) Thank you for setting me the right way! :)

Comment: @Grolldash, sure, on SO solutions will be always given as per shown samples only, so its better to let everything know on a single shot itself(no changing question later :) ).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk. If your first line is always the same.

```
echo 'Symbol,Name,Sector,Market Cap $K,Last,Links'
awk 'NR>1 && NF=5' RS='\n ' ORS='\n' FS='\n' OFS=',' file
```

Output:

```
Symbol,Name,Sector,Market Cap $K,Last,Links
AAPL,Apple Inc,Computers and Technology,2,006,722,560,118.03
AMGN,Amgen Inc,Medical,132,594,808,227.76
AXP,American Express Company,Finance,91,986,280,114.24
BA,Boeing Company,Aerospace,114,768,960,203.30
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Yep, I always re-learn how much more I need to learn about fully using the built-ins every time I see an answer like this. So much less typing `:)`